# How can I suppress identical footnotes with XSLT/XSL-FO?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

First of all, I'm trying to create a PDF from an XML with help of XSLT, XPath and XSL-FO.

I have an XML with multiple footnotes and I use a template to render them automatically after tag name "note".

**XML:**

```
<document>  
  <ul type='custom-list-1' startdist="0.5cm" gap="0.15cm">
    <li space-before="30pt">
        List-item 1
        <block margin-left="-15pt" margin-right="-15pt" text-align="center">
            <table layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <col number="1" width="30%" />
                <col number="2" width="17%" />
                <col number="3" width="17%" />
                <col number="4" width="17%" />
                <col number="5" width="17%" />                      
                <tbody>
                    <tr font-style="italic">
                        <th>sample title</th>
                        <th colspan="4">sample title</th>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Bla bla bla
                            <note name="name-1">
                                Footnote for "bla bla bla"
                            </note>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            .............
                        </td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Comision Administrare Online Banking
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            .........
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Another... Bla bla bla
                            <note name="name-2">
                                Footnote for "Another... Bbla bla bla"
                            </note>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            ......
                        </td>
                    </tr>                       
                </tbody>                
            </table>                            
        </block>
    </li>
    <li space-before="30pt">List-item 2:        

        <block margin-left="-15pt" text-align="center">
            <table layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <col number="1" width="18%" />
                <col number="2" width="13%" />
                <col number="3" width="13%" />
                <col number="4" width="16%" />                  
                <col number="5" width="13%" />
                <col number="6" width="13%" />
                <col number="7" width="13%" />
                <tbody>
                    <tr font-style="italic">
                        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Sample title</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Sample title</th>                       
                        <th rowspan="2">Sample title</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Sample title</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Sample title</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr font-style="italic">
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>                            
                        <td colspan="2">Some text here</td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            1%
                            <note name="name-3">
                                Footnote for "1%"
                            </note>
                            / 0.5%
                            <note name="name-4">
                                Footnote for "0.5%"
                            </note>
                        </td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>                          
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>                            
                        <td colspan="2">Sample text</td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            1%
                            <note name="name-3">
                                Footnote for "1%"
                            </note>
                            / 0.5%
                            <note name="name-4">
                                Footnote for "0.5%"
                            </note>
                        </td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>                          
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>                            
                        <td colspan="2">Sample text</td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            1%
                            <note name="name-3">
                                Footnote for "1%"
                            </note>
                            / 0.5%
                            <note name="name-4">
                                Footnote for "0.5%"
                            </note>
                        </td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>                          
                    </tr>                       
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </block>
    </li>
    <li space-before="30pt">List-item 3
        <block margin-left="-15pt" text-align="center">
            <table layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <col number="1" width="25%" />
                <col number="2" width="15%" />
                <col number="3" width="15%" />
                <col number="4" width="22%" />
                <col number="5" width="22%" />                      
                <tbody>
                    <tr font-style="italic">
                        <th colspan="2">Sample title</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Sample title</th>
                        <th>Sample title</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                            
                        <td colspan="2">Sample text</td>                            
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0%</td>
                        <td>0%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                            
                        <td colspan="2">Sample text</td>                            
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0.05%<note name="name-5">Footnote for "0.05%"</note></td>
                        <td>0.05%</td>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>                            
                        <td colspan="2">Sample text</td>                            
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0%</td>
                        <td>0%</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </block>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="note.data" >
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">justify</xsl:attribute>        
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">normal</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:key name="by-name" match="//note[@name]" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="note">
    <xsl:call-template name="note" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="note">
    <xsl:param name="unique-elements" 
       select="current()[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('by-name', @name)[1])]"/>     
    <xsl:param name="identical-elements" 
       select="current()[not(generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('by-name', @name)[1]))]"/>

    <xsl:if test="$unique-elements">
        <xsl:variable name="element" select="$unique-elements"/>

        <fo:footnote>       
            <fo:inline baseline-shift="super" font-size="75%" color="red">
                <xsl:number level="any" count="//note[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('by-name', @name)[1])]" format="(1)" />
            </fo:inline>

            <fo:footnote-body xsl:use-attribute-sets="note.data">   
                <fo:block color="blue">                             
                    <fo:inline baseline-shift="super" font-size="75%">
                        <xsl:number level="any" count="//note[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('by-name', @name)[1])]" format="(1)" />
                    </fo:inline>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$element" />                                              
                </fo:block>
            </fo:footnote-body>
        </fo:footnote>          
    </xsl:if>           

    <xsl:if test="$identical-elements">
        <fo:inline baseline-shift="super" font-size="75%" color="green">
            <xsl:number level="any" count="//note[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('by-name', @name)[1])]" format="(1)" />
        </fo:inline>            
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**PDF output:**

[image]

So, I managed to suppress the identical footnotes and maintain the count of the unique footnotes (in image colored with red) and add the last count value for the identical footnotes (in image colored with green).

The problem now is that I can't figure it out how can I maintain the same count value for the identical footnotes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where you want to put your select statement? Or should those be match statements and replace your `<xsl:template match="note">`? Also you shold show some of your source XML and maybe more of your stylesheet, it probably makes a difference from where that template is applied.

Comment: @TobiasKlevenz - I edited the post. Now I think is enough to make an ideea... Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand what your desired output is. My guess is you want tp keep counting the identical footnotes so the green 4's would be 5,6,7,8 and than your footer line for those would read (4)(5)(6)(7)(8)Footnote for "0,5%" ...is that correct?

Comment: No. The footnotes numbering for unique footnotes are correct and the footer line for those are correct. I want that the green ones to be also (3) and (4) because they all are identical and they should have the same counted number and just a unique explanation in the <fo:footnote-body>.

Comment: I added the XML for the output PDF...

Comment: I may be wrong,but I think you are asking if a formatting engine will understand that you specifying two things that happen to fall on the same page as being the same thing.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't so clear, but I think that you are right and it seems that you can achieve that (what I want from that XML) by using @TobiasKlevenz solution. Btw...I'm new to XML/XSLT/XPath/XSL-FO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a solution, but without using xsl:number, that usually gives me too much of a headache, but since you have been using level="any" it doesn't really matter:

```
<xsl:template match="note">
    <!-- 
        counts unique preceding notes starting from first note with current @name
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="number"
        select="count((//note[@name=current()/@name])[1]/preceding::note[not(@name=../preceding::note/@name)]) + 1"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- if there is no preceding note with same name -->
        <xsl:when test="not(preceding::note/@name=current()/@name)">
            <fo:footnote>
                <fo:inline baseline-shift="super" font-size="75%" color="red">(<xsl:value-of
                        select="$number"/>)</fo:inline>

                <fo:footnote-body>
                    <fo:block color="blue">
                        <xsl:if test="@margin-left">
                            <xsl:attribute name="margin-left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@margin-left"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <fo:inline baseline-shift="super" font-size="75%">(<xsl:value-of select="$number"
                            />)</fo:inline>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:footnote-body>

            </fo:footnote>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:inline baseline-shift="super" font-size="75%" color="red">(<xsl:value-of
                    select="$number"/>)</fo:inline>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>


</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks man! That was the solution I looked for. I have just 1-2 weeks of XML/XSLT/XPath/XSL-FO, so I can't find or understand everything, but with practice I hope I'll do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to group the identical notes and then select the first one from each group. With XSLT 2.0 you can use the `group-by` atribute. In XSLT 1.0 you can do this creating a key for all notes:

```
<xsl:key name="notes" match="//note" use="@name"/>
```

And then calling your template using the predicate shown below:

```
<xsl:template match="parent-element">
...
     <xsl:apply-templates select="note[generate-id(.) = generate-id( key('notes', @name)[1])]" />
...
</xsl:template>
```

The expression compares the current `note` (`.`) with the first item in the group of `note`s with the same `@name`, so you are selecting the first item of each group.

You will also have to fix your node-count and restrict it to the reduced set (since it is counting all nodes including the duplicate ones):

```
note[generate-id(.) = generate-id( key('notes', @name)[1])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, but I already found a similar answer in other post and updated that one like in the new edit. I also added a print-screen with a test PDF and as you can see there are new issues there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AH Formatter, you can suppress duplicate footnotes on the same page by using the aptly named `axf:suppress-duplicate-footnote` extension property.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#axf.suppress-duplicate-footnote and the "Footnote arrangement in the column document (axf:footnote-position)" sample from https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/